# PHP: "->" not working on mysql resultset

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I have a strange behaviour. Untilo today I was using -> to retrieve member variables from the mysql resultset, such as

```
$username = $result->user_name
```

But this is not working in my current project.

```
$sth = self::$dbConnection->prepare("SELECT user_id, user_name FROM users");                              
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch();

$test = $result->user_password_hash; // $test is null

$test = $result["user_password_hash"]; // this works
```

????

Comment: Well is that `FROM   users;` a question or code typo?

Comment: the code has massive syntax errors that even the SO code formatter is picking up. I'd fix that first.

Comment: close this statement properly `FROM   users;` to `FROM   users" );`

Comment: `$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);`(PDO) -http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php OR `$result = $sth->fetch_object()`(mysqli) - http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php?

Comment: Does sth->fetch actually return an object?

Comment: They edited out the parse error and the problem is reproducible.

Answer (score 4):

After fixing the parse error, if you want an object:

```
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Or:

```
$result = $sth->fetchObject();
```

Or set the mode before using `fetch()`:

```
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Comment: Good point. What happens if I am just expecting one row?

Comment: @AntonSack: `fetch()` only returns 1 row `fetchAll()` returns all.

Comment: Thanks, I understood the mistake I made.

Answer (score 1):

As from [PDOStatement::fetch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) `fetch()` is returning an array both indexed and associative. The arrow (`->`) is meant to access to object properties (or methods). To have and object instead of an array you can call `fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)` instead.